# PHP is returning html response after processing POST request from angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, post

I have angularjs post request as:

```
var loginApp = angular.module("loginApp",[]);
loginApp.controller('loginController', function 
loginController($scope,$http,$window) {

    $scope.submitHandle = function() {
        var req = {
            url: '../login.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                username: $scope.Username,
                password: $scope.Userpassword,
            }

        };
        $http(req).then(function success(response) {
            var data = response.data;
            if(data.returnCode ==200) {
            alert("Welcome : "+ data.username);
                $window.location = '../webapp/html/user.html';
            }
            else {
                alert("User does not exist");
            }
    }, function(response) {
        alert("Error on server side");
    });
    }
});
```

This request is passed to login.php which is as follows :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username1 = "root"; 
$password1 = "abcd";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=ITC_MANAGEMENT", $username1, $password1);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$postdata=file_get_contents("php://input");
$request=json_decode($postdata,true);
$username=$request->username;
$password=$request->password;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT UserId, Password from USER_INFO WHERE UserID='".$username."' && Password='".$password."'");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($row > 0){
$json_array=array();
   $json_array['returnCode']=200;
     $json_array['username']="user1";

          echo  json_encode($json_array);

} else{
   $json_array=array("returnCode"=>201,"username"=>"user1");

  echo json_encode($json_array);
}
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Now, when I am checking response.data, it is present as follows:

```
"<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\itc\login.php on line <i>11</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>247504</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\itc\login.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\login.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\itc\login.php on line <i>12</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0006</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>247504</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\itc\login.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\login.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
{"returnCode":200,"username":"user1"}"
```

As seen, I was expecting `response.data = {"returnCode":200,"username":"user1"}"` but I don't know why is HTML present.
This was just a simple test to see whether post is working. 
I am new to php and angular and stuck at this point. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you read it?

Comment: it seems to be your environment PHP error configuration... see the HTML rendered here: https://jsbin.com/pinitipeku/edit?html,output

Comment: You have an error on line 11 and 12 which is the `$username = $request->username` and `$password = $request->password`. It looks like that $request variable isn't defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to handle how PHP throw errrors to your application client.

```
<?php
// Turn off error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report runtime errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_error_reporting.asp
reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @BadalJoshi great! Make sure you have access to this errors from a log file or a log handler PHP package like Monolog.

Answer (score 0):

If you will go through that html response then you can see that you have some non-object issue on line 11 and 12. So I think you should try to fix that.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\itc\login.php on line <i>11</i>

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\itc\login.php on line <i>12</i>
```

As per your code above line 11 qnd 12 is

```
$username=$request->username;
$password=$request->password;
```

which gets username and password from json object $request.

For geting post data you are using file_get_contents.

```
$postdata=file_get_contents("php://input");
```

and then your json object.

```
$request=json_decode($postdata,true);
```

Please check that you are getting $postdata in php.
For capturing the postdata in php you can use $_POST[].

using **error_reporting(0);** will fix your issue but to make your code proper you should fix your Notice which you are appearing in html response

Comment: Thanks. I could solve the error in`$username=$request->username;
$password=$request->password;` by using `$username=$request['username'];
$password=$request['password'];`